# Fetching data from 3 related tables with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, if-statement, sum, inner-join

I want to get sum of the prices and items columns which are related to 3 tables.I am trying with `INNER JOIN` in the following script. It only displays 1 invoice total. And else statement is not displaying 0 When data is 0.

```
function TotalRecord($total){
global $db;
$date = date("Y-m-d");
     $query = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(a.prices), sum(a.item) FROM items a INNER 
    JOIN invoice_items b ON a.item_id = b.item_id INNER JOIN invoices c ON 
    b.invoiceId = c.invoiceId  WHERE c.invoice_date = :date ");
    $query->bindParam(':date', $date);
    $query->execute();
    for($i=0; 
             $rows = $query->fetch(); 
    $i++){
         $totalPrice = $rows['sum(a.prices)'];
         $totalitems = $rows['sum(a.item)'];
         $array = array('total' => $totalPrice , 'items' => $totalitems );

        if(count($array) > 0)
        {
            echo $array[$total];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "0";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple SUM function, you should probably use the GROUP BY instruction. See below
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp 
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: i have tried this there is no example similar to my question, it's confusing me.

Comment: Add the group by after the where clause

Comment: you mean like this `SELECT sum(a.prices), sum(a.item) FROM (items a INNER 
JOIN invoice_items b ON a.item_id = b.item_id INNER JOIN invoices c ON 
b.invoiceId = c.invoiceId )  WHERE c.invoice_date = :date  group by  b.item_id,b.invoiceid`

Comment: And what about else statement ?

Comment: Yes, for the else statement, you could check the value of sum(a.prices) (=0 or >0)

Comment: `if(count($array) > 0)
        {
            echo $array[$total];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "0";
        }` I am trying with this but its not working

Comment: Try `if($row['sum(a.prices)'] > 0 || $row['sum(a.item)'] > 0) { //Something } else {}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT sum(a.prices), sum(a.item) FROM (items a INNER 
JOIN invoice_items b ON a.item_id = b.item_id INNER JOIN invoices c ON 
b.invoiceId = c.invoiceId )  group by  b.item_id,b.invoiceid WHERE c.invoice_date = :date
```

Comment: it's giving this error `error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE c.invoice_date = '2018-06-10'' at line 1`